# How to get neighborhood values count using a geoprocessing tool in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst

I have a [raster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLWvF.jpg) (black=0, red=1, and white=NoData). I am wondering if there is any tool in arcgis which can help me only count number of 0s and 1s separately in a 3*3 neighborhood. I need an attribute table with that information. Any hint of relevant tool would be appreciative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the tool you want is [Focal Statistics](http://bit.ly/1jQq5Li) and use the SUM statistics type (for your 1's). You'll have to run it a second time for the 0s but you'll have to turn your 0's into 1's using [Equal To](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Equal_To/009z000000m4000000/) tool so that the SUM statistic will return the count .

UPDATE

Your comment said you wanted to use arcpy so here's a code sample of how to call those tools through arcpy. I haven't tested this code but I think it should work for you...

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
inRaster = Raster("<<yourPathHere>>")
redCount = FocalStatistics(EqualTo(inRaster,1),NbrRectangle(3, 3, "CELL"),"SUM")
blackCount = FocalStatistics(EqualTo(inRaster,0),NbrRectangle(3, 3, "CELL"),"SUM")
redCount.save("<<yourOutputPath>>")
blackCount.save("<<yourOutputPath>>")
```

`

Comment: Thanks. I was trying it with arcpy but your solution saved me sometime.

Answer (score -1):

Hi You can see this paper:  A novel method for detecting and counting overlapping tracks in SSNTD by image processing techniques

10.1016/j.radmeas.2016.04.009